# Why can't I debug my Go project using docker in VS Code?

Tags: docker, go, visual-studio-code, air

I'm starting a project in Go, which I will work using docker. These are my files:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM golang:1.22

WORKDIR /go/src/gitlab.com/main/server

COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .

RUN go mod download

RUN go install github.com/cosmtrek/air@latest
RUN go install github.com/swaggo/swag/cmd/swag@latest
RUN go install github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest

EXPOSE 2345
EXPOSE 80
```

**Docker compose:**

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  service-influxdb:
    image: go-time-series
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
    command: air -c .air.toml
    volumes:
      - ../:/go/src/gitlab.com/main/server
    ports:
      - 8080:80
      - 10000:2345
    environment:
      - WEB_APP_VERSION=0.0.1
      - WEP_APP_TITLE=Thori influx-DB
      - WEP_APP_DESCRIPTION=Micro service for the manage of the influx-db services
      - ENVIRONMENT=dev
      - HOST=localhost:8080
      - INFLUX_URL=http://localhost:8086
      - INFLUX_TOKEN=###############
      - INFLUX_ORG=123acs
      - INFLUX_MINIMUN_DATE=1677-09-21 00:12:44
      - INFLUX_MAXIMUN_DATE=2100-01-01 00:00:00
```

**.air.toml:**

```
root = "."
testdata_dir = "testdata"
tmp_dir = "tmp"

[build]
  args_bin = []
  bin = "./tmp/main"
  full_bin = "dlv exec --accept-multiclient --headless --listen :2345 --api-version 2 ./tmp/main"
  pre_cmd = ["swag init -g ./cmd/main.go --cf multi"]
  cmd = "go build -o ./tmp/main ./cmd/main.go"
  post_cmd = []
  delay = 0
  exclude_dir = ["assets", "tmp", "vendor", "testdata", "docs"]
  exclude_file = []
  exclude_regex = ["_test.go"]
  exclude_unchanged = true
  follow_symlink = true
  include_dir = []
  include_ext = ["go", "tpl", "tmpl", "html"]
  include_file = []
  kill_delay = "0s"
  log = "build-errors.log"
  poll = false
  poll_interval = 0
  rerun = false
  rerun_delay = 500
  send_interrupt = false
  stop_on_error = false

[color]
  app = ""
  build = "yellow"
  main = "magenta"
  runner = "green"
  watcher = "cyan"

[log]
  main_only = false
  time = true

[misc]
  clean_on_exit = true

[screen]
  clear_on_rebuild = true
  keep_scroll = true
```

**launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug in Docker",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "attach",
            "mode": "remote",
            "remotePath": "/go/src/gitlab.com/main/server",
            "port": 10000,
            "host": "127.0.0.1",
            "showLog": true,
            "trace": "log",
            "logOutput": "rpc"
        }
    ]
}

func main() {
    port := flag.Int("port", 80, "Listening port")
    flag.Parse()

    if config.Cfg.Environment == "prod" {
        gin.ForceConsoleColor()
        gin.SetMode(gin.ReleaseMode)
    }

    router := gin.Default()
    loadSwagger(router)
    loadAPI(router)
    router.Run(fmt.Sprintf(":%d", *port))
}
```

But when I raise my container and start the debug it does not recognize the breakpoints

[image]

What could be happening? Why can't it find the file? (the path is correct) How to solve it? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding substitutePath instead of remotePath in the launch.json:

```
        {
            "name": "Debug in Docker",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "attach",
            "mode": "remote",
            // "remotePath": "/go/src/gitlab.com/main/server",
            "substitutePath": [
                { "from": "${workspaceFolder}", "to": "/go/src/gitlab.com/main/server"},
            ],
            "port": 10000,
            "host": "127.0.0.1",
            "showLog": true,
            "trace": "log",
            "logOutput": "rpc"
        }
```

https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/wiki/debugging#remote-debugging